# Losing auto-complete after index-signature in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface for an object and I need to **auto-complete** when using keys of that object, but when I am specifying the object I don't see tips of IDE and losing **auto-complete**.

I know the solution will be like

```js
const makeProvider = (config: Provider) => config;
const obj = makeProvider({...});
```

But when I need to write:

```js
interface newProvider {
    token: string,
    api: ??? //If Provider - I will lose auto-complete, 
          but this keys logic equals Provider interface :(
}
```

```js
interface Provider {
    [key: string]: string    
};

let obj: Provider = {
    api: '...'
};

obj. //no auto-complete
```

I expect the **auto-complete** in IDE after using this interfaces, but it doesn't appear. Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: So maybe it's IDE problem, not your code? What IDE you are using?

Comment: vs code. when I creating obj with Provider interface my ide gives me tips - its okey. But when i creating the second interface of token and provider interface - i losing auto-complete